# JQUERY .load not working with window.location in firefox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

Here is my code

```
$("#cancel").click(function(){
    $("#destroy").load("../../ajax/destroyroom.ajax.php");
    window.location = "game.php";
})
```

I've try this on Chrome and it is working

the purpose of destroyroom.ajax.php is to delete a certain record on the database I load it on a DIV so that it will delete the record and then it will be redirected on another page using the window.location but .load function is not working on fire it did not delete the record on the dbase.

any idea and tips?

thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in either the console or firebug?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead (untested):

```
$("#cancel").click(function(){
    $("#destroy").load("../../ajax/destroyroom.ajax.php", function() {
        window.location = "game.php";
    });        
})
```

This will redirect the user, after loading was complete.

**Edit:**
Also try to give the `load()` function the full path to your php file. eg. `example.org/ajax/destroyroom.ajax.php`

Comment: What was it, my code example, or the tip with the full path? I'm just asking for others.

Comment: +1 for the quick solution. @OP be aware of `window.location` can't be set directly in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use:

```
window.location.href = "game.php";
```

to have the redirect work in all browsers.

2nd call the redirect within the complete handler:

```
$("#cancel").click(function(){
    $("#destroy").load("../../ajax/destroyroom.ajax.php", function() {
        window.location.href = "game.php";
    });        
})
```

If you call it directly, after the ajax call, this may be broken, because of the redirect will be executed directly after the ajax call.

3rd: The ajax call may be cached. You can turn cache off globally or directly using `$.ajax()` and set the option `cache:false` instead of `load()`.